# List with street's suggestion names

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

Is it possible, in an iOS context, to somehow return a list of street's suggestion names, like the Maps application? For instance, I type "Central" and it returns a list of streets that contain the word "Central" in their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built into iOS that will do that. I would suggest using the Google Geocoding API with `UISearchDisplayController`. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Don't think its able to return multiple suggestions. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it can. You can also set priority of results by region.